# Spark SQL 1.5.2 missing JDBC driver for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I see in the Spark SQL documentation that a temporary table can be created directly onto a remote PostgreSQL table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE <table_name>
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
url "jdbc:postgresql://<PostgreSQL_Hostname_IP>/<database_name>",
dbtable "impressions"
);
```

When I run this against our PostgreSQL server, I get the following error.

`Error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://<PostgreSQL_Hostname_IP>/<database_name> (state=,code=0)`

Can someone help me understand why this is?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

## JDBC Driver

A JDBC driver translates your JDBC calls and SQL into code specific to your particular database server. The driver mediates the data exchange, converting between SQL data types and Java types.

You must make a [JDBC Driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) available to your Java app at runtime. You need to obtain an appropriate driver and place it in a location where it will be on the [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)) so the JVM can access it when needed.

You need to edit that JDBC URL string to insert your particular host name/address, your particular database name, your particular database password.

Projects like Spark do not bundle JDBC drivers. To do so is not their job, and would not be practical to maintain the latest updates for all the versions of all the drivers for all the databases.

If using a [Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) [container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container), note that JDBC drivers are special in that they may need to be placed in a folder for the container itself rather than in a folder for your web app as with other regular libraries.

For Postgres you have a choice of drivers.

The [classic driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org) is compatible with older versions of Java and Postgres. This driver is an official part of the Postgres project. Open-source and free-of-cost.

[pgjdbc-ng](https://github.com/impossibl/pgjdbc-ng) is a “next-generation” driver supporting only the most recent versions of Java and Postgres. Open-source and free-of-cost.

Commercial [JDBC vendors](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-136695.html) provide Postgres drivers as well.

Comment: I added these lines to the spark-default.conf on the Spark SQL Thrift JDBC/ODBC Server: spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/share/java/postgresql-9.3-1104.jdbc41.jar, spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/share/java/postgresql-9.3-1104.jdbc41.jar.
I was able to create the table, but when I query the table, I get the same error again. It looks like I’m getting close. Are there any other things that I have to do that you can think of?

Comment: @Benjamin Ignore the Spark stuff. Write your own plain direct JDBC to get the hang of it. Once you are properly interacting with the database, then go back to Spark.